# multiple nested grid not expanding on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a data set that requires multiple nested grids. I am currently using JavaScript/Jquery to collapse/show the nested grids. It works on the 1st level of nesting but not the 2nd level. When clicking on the second level it does not do anything. when debugging it goes through the code but does not show/hide the grid.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
            var img = "img" + divname;
            if ($("#" + img).attr("src") == "images/plus.png") {
                $("#" + img)
                .closest("tr")
                .after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '100%'>" + $("#" + divname)
                .html() + "</td></tr>");
                $("#" + img).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
            } else {
                $("#" + img).closest("tr").next().remove();
                $("#" + img).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
            }
        }
    </script>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No Info"
        OnRowDataBound="gv1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("id") %>');">
                        <img alt="Details" id='imgdiv<%# Eval("id") %>' src="images/plus.png" /></a>
                    <div id='div<%# Eval("id") %>' style="display: none;">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gv2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="false"
                            OnRowDataBound="gv2_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('divMail<%# Eval("number") %>');">
                                            <img alt="DetailsMail" id='imgdivMail<%# Eval("number") %>' src="images/plus.png" /></a>
                                        <div id='divMail<%# Eval("number") %>' style="display: none;">
                                            <asp:GridView ID="gv3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="df1" HeaderText="name" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="df2" HeaderText="name2" />
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="df1" HeaderText="name" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="df5" HeaderText="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="df6" HeaderText="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="df7" HeaderText="name" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: For second level nested gird,  1. Does the image icon changes to minus? 2. `$("#" + img).closest("tr")` does it return any table row?

Comment: no the icon does not change. it does not return any thing. nothing happens when the icon is clicked.

Comment: I suggest add “debugger;” statement inside divexpandcollapse method and then try expanding 2nd level nested grid. Check if it hits the debugger statement.

Comment: I have added a debugger and it enters the script and goes through the section to display the 2nd inner grid but it does still does not display.

Comment: I suggest you inspect the generated html once the page is rendered using the Developer's tool. For second level grid, `<img id="imgdivMail{id}" ...` should have a parent `<tr>` element and `$("#" + img).closest("tr")` should return that parent tr element.

Comment: I have found something else out. if I expand the first level and click to expand the second level. nothing happens. If I collapse the first level and re-expand it the 2nd level is expanded. It seems like the jquery is not refreshing like it should be. how do I trigger jquery to refresh the code in grid? 

Yes, there is a <tr> element

Comment: "if I expand the first level and click to expand the second level. nothing happens" so when you click to expand the second level have you confirmed that `divexpandcollapse` method is executed with correct divMail parameter?

Comment: yes, i have validated that the divexpandcollapse  method is executed

Comment: Add 2nd level of gridview inside Panel and add Panel under Item-Template. Try this [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx)

Comment: Gaurav, I have tried changing the div to panel and there was no change. I also tried to use the complete example from the link you posted. However, it is not working at all. since '.live' is not longer usable in the current jqeury version I have tried to update it with the '.on' but can't get it to work on even the first level.

Comment: here is the script I am using  
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#divgrid").on("click", "[src*=plus]", function () {
        //$("[src*=plus]").on("click", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        });
        $("[src*=minus]").on("click", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        });
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the nested girdviews working.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
                var img = "img" + divname;
                if ($("#" + img).attr("src") == "images/plus.png") {
                    $("#" + img).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
                    $("#" + divname).show();
                } else {
                    $("#" + divname).hide();
                    $("#" + img).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
                }
            }
        </script>
```

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No Info" OnRowDataBound="gv1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("id") %>');">
                            <img alt="Details" id='imgdiv<%# Eval("id") %>' src="images/plus.png" /></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="df5" HeaderText="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="df6" HeaderText="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="df7" HeaderText="name" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id='divMail<%# Eval("id") %>' style="display: none; margin-left: 25px;">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gv2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="false" OnRowDataBound="gv2_RowDataBound">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('divMail<%# Eval("number") %>');">
                                                        <img alt="DetailsMail" id='imgdivMail<%# Eval("number") %>' src="images/plus.png" /></a>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="df1" HeaderText="name" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div id='divMail<%# Eval("number") %>' style="display: none;">
                                                                <asp:GridView ID="gv3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                                                    <Columns>
                                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="df1" HeaderText="name" />
                                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="df2" HeaderText="name2" />
                                                                    </Columns>
                                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I ended up using the jquery show() and Hide() functions. I then modified the code to put the nested grid in a templatefield on the last column. I put the 'tr' and 'td' blocks around the grid so it would display correctly when expanded.